# CSS : Firefox right click selects all on my site...why?

Tags: css, firefox, contextmenu, selection, right-click

I have built a context menu but have found annoyingly that **when I right click on my site in firefox all text and images just seem to randomly get selected**. It is not a JS issue as I have removed all JS from the site. Thinking it must be a css issue. I have never encountered anything like this before...

I don't have an example page to show I'm afraid. Has anyone experienced this before in Firefox. I am using the latest FF4.

Cheers Guys!

*UPDATE:***

Here is a pasting of the pure html from the page that is having issues,
http://jsbin.com/aneja4/3/edit

Answer (score 1):

did you try to disable all your addons you have installed? maybe one of them is causing the problem.
I have FF 4 but neven encountered this problem before.

And I could be wrong but I don't know of any css code that would be able to select text. it's pure for the design and structure of the site. it will be mostlikely a js problem or something else

Comment: It's only occuring on my site not others

Comment: then there must be something on you site that is causing the problem. What I can't tell without a preview I'm afraid. Do you have the web developer toolbar? it will show you errors and you can see if there are still scripts on your site.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this too...  I think it has something to do with the way the site is structured...  If you have nexted divs, or a div that does not quite cover the entire page, a right click on the parent div seems to select everything in the nested div.  It's quite annoying... especially when trying to build a custom context menu, or use the default menu to refresh the page...

Any fixes/changes that we should know about for FF that is causing this?  I'm using FF4 and XP (yeah, yeah... corp. system)

JF

Answer (score 1):

It's likely a problem with your HTML layout that firefox is struggling to work with. But without seeing any code, it's not possible to speculate any further down that path. @JDF's suggestions may help you, though.

If you can't work it out, and can't live with it, you could just disable the ability to select text.

In Firefox (and other standards-compliant browsers), you'd use the CSS `user-select: none;`.

See this question for more info on how to achieve this: [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Comment: Here is a pasting of the pure html from the page that is having issues, http://jsbin.com/aneja4/3/edit

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by having a `contentEditable` element on your page. Any element (other than `body` it seems) that contains editable content will be highlighted/selected when you right click on it in Firefox (4.0 and 5.0 is all I can confirm). If everything on your page is wrapped in a `div` it'll appear that the whole page is selected. If you (can) right-click somewhere on the `body` the regular context menu should work.

Although I can't see any instances of `contentEditable` in your code on jsbin, it could be added by a script that I can't see (possibly even modernizr?).

I think this is related (although it doesn't match exactly)
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/766166

http://aloha-editor.org/ exhibits the same behaviour when right-clicking anywhere inside the `#wrapper` `div`.